# Xaml - Binding in FallBackValue

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, binding, telerik

How can i make two bindings on a column in grid, in the way that if first binding is empty or null, second binding will be used. I have tried to do that with FallbackValue property but you can't make binding inside it only static values.
Here some code, which is more than words!

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView">
     <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName,
            FallbackValue=Binding FirstName2}"  //You cant do that!
            Header="First Name" />
     </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

There must be someway to do it in xaml! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least two ways:

**First Solution (solved in the DataContext):** Add a property to your `DataContext` type, something like *ResolvedFirstName* and the value is either taken from *FirstName* or *FirstName2*, and when either of the two is changed the *ResolvedFirstName* is re-evaluated.

```
public string ResolvedFirstName {
    get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? FirstName2 : FirstName; }
}

public string FirstName {
    get {...}
    set {...
        RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ResolvedFirstName");}
}

public string FirstName2 {
    get {...}
    set {...
        RaisePropertyChanged("FirstName2");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ResolvedFirstName");}
}
```

**Second Solution (solved in the View):** Add a `StringMultiplexer` as `StaticResource` that binds to both properties, it offers an *Output* property your column can bind against.

```
<RadGridView>
    <RadGridView.Resources>
        <StringMultiplexer x:Key="FirstNameMux"
            HighPrioString="{Binding FirstName}"
            LowPrioString="{Binding FirstName2}"/>
    </RadGridView.Resources>
    <RadGridView.Columns>
        <GridViewDataColumn
            DataMemberBinding="{Binding Output, Source={StaticResource FirstNameMux}}"/>
```

and code:

```
public class StringMultiplexer : DependencyObject
{
    public string LowPrioString
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue( LowPrioStringProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( LowPrioStringProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LowPrioStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "LowPrioString", typeof( string ), typeof( StringMultiplexer ), new PropertyMetadata( DetermineOutput ) );

    public string HighPrioString
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue( HighPrioStringProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( HighPrioStringProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighPrioStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "HighPrioString", typeof( string ), typeof( StringMultiplexer ), new PropertyMetadata( DetermineOutput ) );

    public string Output
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue( OutputProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( OutputProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutputProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Output", typeof( string ), typeof( StringMultiplexer ), null );

    private static void DetermineOutput( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ((StringMultiplexer) d).DetermineOutput();
    }

    private void DetermineOutput()
    {
        Output = (string.IsNullOrEmpty( HighPrioString )) ? LowPrioString : HighPrioString;
    }
}
```

As I typed the second solutiuon I grew the doubt that this solution does not work in your specific case. I used the `StringMultiplexer` myself and it is working as intended. The problem I see with your case is: the GridViewDataColumn is no FrameworkElement (as far as I remember) but just a mere Column-definition-object that provides a blueprint for when actual cell controls or row controls are instantiated, and the DataMemberBinding will most likely be resolved against the item object for which a row is created. Maybe you need to derive from GridViewDataColumn and implement the multiplexer there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DataTriggers for that, Something like this

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView">
  <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name">
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewDataColumn}">
              <Setter Property="DataMemberBinding" Value="{Binding FirstName}"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Value="{x:Null}">
                      <Setter Property="DataMemberBinding" Value="{Binding FirstName2}"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Style>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
  </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's a silverlight project and this doesn't work